# Is that possible for local p2p connection with encryption and remote p2p connection with encryption within the same application?

Tags: encryption

on the wiki page of Rustdesk, it states "the connection is unecrypted, please do not send us issue about this." for local direct IP.

BUT, Rustdesk is intended "Virtual / remote desktop infrastructure for everyone! ", (so not localdesktop)

While Rustdesk claims Rustdesk is encrypted between client and server, which seems to be a more complicated task has completed, BUT they can not do local p2p connection with encryption? and states upfront that "please do not send us issue about this." (local connection without encryption)

So the question is : can we have p2p connection with encryption locally (without a server) and remotely (with a relay server) within the same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can we have p2p connection with encryption locally (without a server) and remotely (with a relay server) within the same application?

Certainly, it's possible - the application (probably) needs to know which mode any specific connection is using (direct or relayed) in order to know who it is supposed to authenticate the peer as, but that looks entirely feasible.

Now, I suppose that the designers of RustDesk might have excluded such a possibility; perhaps they inherently assume that you'll always be encrypting to a relay server that they own.  However, that would be a decision they made.

Comment: the relay server is alway open source,  can be self-hosted.  but this designed seem like we can  use relay server  host it on the same machine as one of the client to have a remote encrypted connection.

Comment: @BenjaminC: if the relay server can be self-hosted, why doesn't one of the PCs host the relay server; it can talk to the other PC via that relay server, and so all communication going "in the air" will be encrypted?